# Сколько hangfire задач может выполнятся одновременно?

Tags: .net, hangfire

Всем привет. 
Я разрабатываю высоконагруженный проект, в котором должно будет работать 500-1000+ задач одновременно.
На офф. сайте я увидел информацию о очередях HangFire, однако не нашёл информации, сколько задач может выполнять одновременно, и после какого лимита задачи попадают в очередь.
 Это очень важно для меня, т.к. задача должна начать выполняется сразу после запроса, иначе произойдёт ошибка.

Comment: Количество именно одновременных задач будет ограничено ядрами процессора.  Я думаю, что Вы сильно переоценивает свой проект

Answer (score 0):

Кол-во одновременных задач ограничено кол-вом потоков вашего процессора. 
В моём случае 20 ядер 40 потоков. Максимум 40 задач одновременно.